# Real Time Friends Locations Tracking In React Native?

Tags: react-native, location

I want to create a react native app that will plot friends locations on a google map and update in real time (perhaps every few seconds / minutes)

How can I best achieve this? as all tutorials I have found simply show how to track the users own phone and not how to transmit and receive others locations

Would it be achieved via transmitting the users location via a web socket and having a web socket on the server that listens for changes and then broadcasts the changes out to all the other clients? Or can I achieve this with traditional http restful api's, any advice / direction on achieving this if im correct

I would appreciate any guidance on achieving this result

Comment: Firebase to your rescue.

Comment: In what way?  Can you elaborate as to which features? I already have a custom backend so have no need for Firestore etc

Comment: If you already have a backend setup, then yes go with socket.io or something. I am working on an app that uses realtime user locations, and I use Firebase for that. It is very simple to listen to events from firebase.